# I can not install printer Canon ic d860

Tags: printing, samba, windows-xp, canon

**[Translated Post]**
I'm new and I'm installing a printer where I work to change the OS 8 computers before with "win xp" Take and operating a lexmark e120 I was not previously tested drivers, and now I have faults with the multifunctional Canon imageCLASS d860 in the list when I add it in samba shows any driver for that printer, if anyone knows if it works with another miracle or there is a universal one: P hehe it thank you very much for your help now!
PS the printer is shared on the network and the server machine has win xp OS

Thank you.

**[Original Post]**
Soy novato y ando instalando una impresora en donde trabajo cambie los SO 8 computadoras antes con "win xp"  ya heche a funcionar una lexmark e120 que anteriormente no me daba probando controladores, y ahora  tengo fallas con el multifuncional canon imageclass d860, en el listado a la hora de agregarlo en samba no me aparece algun controlador para esa impresora, si alguien sabe si funciona con otro o de milagro hay uno universal :P jeje pues muchas gracias por la ayuda desde ahora!
pd la impresora esta compartida en red y la máquina con el servidor tiene SO win xp

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install your printer in Ubuntu without needing to look for drivers (search for Canon in the Software Centre). It will show up in Samba once you have it installed.

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia pero no sé como buscarlo desde el centro de software de ubuntu ya he puesto el modelo la marca y pues no me aparece algo referente a canon ic d860.

Comment: @Chikri: no problema mi hermanito ;D

Comment: hey man, i can't do it, i don't know search this package in the software center, how i do it?

Comment: @Chikri: I will have to see if there is not a question on this already (I think there is), and if there is I'll point you to that.